# Getting error to import sparse matrix into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix file, which contains 779641 lines. I named the file as "file_matrix2.dat". Sample of few lines of the file are as follows:

```
0   547 1
1   547 1
2   539 0.500000
2   540 0.500000
3   512 0.333333
3   515 0.333333
```

I want to import this sparse matrix file into matlab. The size of the file is 16MB. The full matrix contained in the file has 237017 rows and and equal numbers of columns. To import this sparse matrix, I use the following commands:

```
load ('C:\Users\Dhan\Desktop\file_matrix2.dat')
and
H=spconvert(file_matrix2)
```

Then an error is displayed, which is:

```
"??? Error using ==> sparse
Index into matrix must be positive.

Error in ==> spconvert at 53
   S = sparse(D(:,1),D(:,2),D(:,3));"
```

Please suggest me to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: is it from c?? matlab takes index from 1. I guess `sparse(D(:,1)+1,D(:,2)+1,D(:,3))` would work

Comment: Yes, I created this file in C++.. I will try it..

Comment: Adding one to each row and column location should work.  Remember that MATLAB starts indexing at 1.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Dohyun and Mr. rayryeng. It works perfectly after adding 1 to each row and column..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding one to each row and column location should work.  Remember that MATLAB starts indexing at 1.